# Running two parallel transactions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, eclipselink

I have method marked by `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
someMethod() {}`. I need to create a test case where I will run this method(first transaction) and before first transaction commit I will run this method parallel in second transaction. I use eclipseLink and java ee. Could you give me some advice how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

(glassfish: so I presume you are working in weld)

In the case of Weld and Hibernate I use (and created) [ejb-cdi-unit](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit/) that allows you to define PersistenceContexts (in Simulation for H2) and handling of transaction annotations quite easily even in multiple threads.

You can try to do your simulation using that (but eclipselink is not supported) or you can try to do something similar (multithreaded persistencecontexts in a Weld-Standalone-Container) with [weld-unit](https://github.com/weld/weld-junit) or [cdi-unit](https://github.com/BrynCooke/cdi-unit).